Promise.withResolvers is not a function when using pdf.js 4.4.168
I am using pdf.js 4.4.168 to render some pdf in browser, today when I use safari 16.4 to open the site, shows error:
Unexpected Application Error!
Promise.withResolvers is not a function. (In 'Promise.withResolvers()', 'Promise.withResolvers' is undefined)
x_@https://tex.poemhub.top/assets/index--WBBKURE.js:35:156906
sV@https://tex.poemhub.top/assets/index--WBBKURE.js:35:152952
@https://tex.poemhub.top/assets/index--WBBKURE.js:45:77451
yl@https://tex.poemhub.top/assets/react-BFk0LVKl.js:32:24264
ur@https://tex.poemhub.top/assets/react-BFk0LVKl.js:32:42277
@https://tex.poemhub.top/assets/react-BFk0LVKl.js:32:40631
P@https://tex.poemhub.top/assets/react-BFk0LVKl.js:17:1585
oe@https://tex.poemhub.top/assets/react-BFk0LVKl.js:17:1954

I am searching from internet that tell me the legacy browser did not support Promise.withResolvers(), we should upgrade the browser to solve this problem. But I still want some old version of user should use the website. Then I tried to use the pdf.js legacy version. What I have tried to download the legacy version, then replace with the legacy one: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases/download/v4.4.168/pdfjs-4.4.168-legacy-dist.zip.
After replace the pdf.worker.min.mjs, still did not fixed this issue.  This is my legacy js: https://tex.poemhub.top/pdfjs-dist/4.4.168/legacy/pdf.worker.min.mjs. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue?

That older version you linked to is still using withResolvers(). You can see it in that pdf.worker.min.mjs file if you search for it. You need to find an older version of that library that does not reference withResolvers() - assuming one even exists. However, browser usage stats show that a tiny fraction of a % of users are actually using Safari < 17. Is this really a problem you need to worry about? You are actively making your site worse and less secure by trying to solve this issue.

ok. I will rethink to solve the issue with the lower version of pdf.js. Maybe a friendly tips is a good solution.

If the error happens running Cypress tests, consider switching Browsers.
In my case, Electron would not cut it when Chrome worked fine.
npx cypress run --browser chrome
